# Differentiation of a function under a double (or multiple) integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to evaluate the integral of the form:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^{t''}\int_{t'}^{t}\omega(t'')\omega(t')dt'dt''\right)
$$
where $\omega$ is a matrix and $0<t'<t''<t$.

I encountered this integral in the second term of the Taylor expansion of path ordered exponential $R(t)=P\exp(\int_0^t\omega (t')dt')$. The result should be $\omega(t)\int_0^t\omega(t')dt'$ but I could not verify it. Could someone give me a hint?

My approach was to move the derivative pass the first integral, breakout the integral and use the fundamental theorem. After that I got:
$$
\int_0^{t''}\left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{t'}^{t''}\omega(t'')\omega(t')dt'\right)+ \omega(t'')\omega(t)\right]dt''
$$

The second term starts to seem right to me, but the interval is 0 to t'', which is not exactly right. But I am not sure what to do with the first term in the bracket. Did I get something wrong here?

Comment: @vitamind I think t' and t'' are independent from t. The formula is on page 50 of this document for your reference in case I was wrong. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/clas.pdf

Comment: Are you familiar with the Leibniz rule?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with it. I read about it and seems like it really close to the form that I have here, but not sure if I am doing that right. It looks like it will be a partial derivative in t when I pass the derivative inside the first integral, then I can use fundamental theorem next.

Comment: @vitamind And this will be quite a dump question but does the fundamental theorem still the same here when I have t' as a lower bound in my integral is in term of dt'? That was the reason I split the interval from t' -> t" and then from t'' -> t above. But I end up stuck with the first term.